# Working with entities, get only part of data

Tags: php, database, entities

I am working with entities (php, custom solution). And I need to take not all data, but some fields.

After long search I found this: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.htm

Here we have a clear description why we can't use not fully filled entity. But I don't clearly understand what decision should I use.

For example, I can get ID, NAME, SURNAME with this way:

```
select id, name, surname from users where ...
```

I don't want to rely on array (that's how Doctrine do in Symfony). Can I use VO or DTO for different tasks?

Comment: I think for simple queries you can use partial object using doctrine. there is no problem with that. but you may have problem with complex queries with associations.